# Add custom text to tweet sheet beside text from textfield

Tags: api, twitter

I want to add a custom text in Tweetsheet beside the text from UITextField. For the same, i am using the following code, but don't know how to extend it further. Any help would be appreciated.

[tweetsheet setInitialText:textfield.text];

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to add all the text you want into a string variable and then use:

```
[tweetsheet setInitialText:myVariable];
```